# Conversion Function with decltype(auto) in C++14

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, auto, decltype

```
class A {
    public:
        int num;
        A ( int param ) : num( param ) {}
        operator decltype( auto )( ){ return num; }
};

class B {
    public:
        int num;
        A objA;
        B ( int param ) : num( param ), objA( param ) {}
      //operator A( )       { return objA; }         // Works               // #1   
      //operator int( )     { return objA; }         // Works               // #2
      //operator char( )    { return objA; }         // Actually Not Needed // #3
      //operator double( )  { return objA; }         // Actually Not Needed // #4
        operator decltype( auto )( ){ return objA; } // Does NOT Work       // #5
};

int main(){

    A objA( 1 );
    int    x1 =   int( objA );
    char   y1 = (char) objA;
    double z1 =        objA;

    B objB( 2 );
    A objA2     = objB;
    int      x2 = objB;
    char     y2 = objB;
    double   z2 = objB;

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile neither with clang nor with gcc, so I assume it is not correct. However, if I comment line #5 and uncomment lines #1 and #2 the program works correctly in both compilers (lines #3 and #4 are not really required).

As far as I know, the necessary conversion sequences are defined in both scenarios. Does anyone know why this program is not correct? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [implicit conversion sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Order_of_the_conversions) could contain only one user-defined conversion. Then the code won't work for `int x2 = objB;`; `B` converts to `A` and `A` converts to `int` are both user-defined conversion.

If you provide the `operator int()` in `B`, it works fine because `B` could be converted to `int` directly. (And also works with `char` and `double`, to which `int` could be converted to by standard conversion.)

Comment: That sounds very interesting, I didn't know about that rule. However, in the second case you say B can be converted to int directly, as far as I can see there are also 2 user-defined conversions (B cannot be converted directly to int because that conversion function is returning A): when I provide `operator int( ) { return objA; }` (this is the first user-defined conversion) it is returning an object of class A, which should be converted to an int with the other user-defined conversion `operator decltype( auto )( ){ return num; }`. Isn't that correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JL Yes, for `return objA;`, `objA` is converted to `int` by the conversion operator defined in `A`. But note it's another conversion sequence; the original conversion sequence (i.e. from `B` to `int`) has finished by the `B::operator int()`, which states that it could do the conversion; how it implement that is another matter.

Comment: OK, I understand what you say, but couldn't I say the same for the other case? I guess the answer is no, and that is why it is wrong. So using `operator decltype( auto )( ){ return objA; }` means both user-defined conversions are in the same sequence, but in the other case (`operator int( ) { return objA; }`) there are two different conversion sequences, is that correct? I don't fully understand why in one case is the same conversion sequence and in the other case it is considered two different conversion sequence, but it sounds like correct answer. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Just for the record, C++14 Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2014), Section 12.3, Paragraph 4 `At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.`. By the way, it is interesting that trying `int x2 = (A) objB;` compiles and executes correctly with the second case (`operator decltype( auto )( ){ return objA; }`)

Comment: @JL For `int x2 = objB;`, `B` has to be converted to `int`, that's one conversion; for which only one-time user defined conversion is allowed, that means we can't invoke another user-defined conversion operation **after** one. But for the only one user-defined conversion performed, how it's implemented (e.g. it might perform other conversions in its function body) doesn't count.

Comment: @JL `int x2 = (A) objB;` is splitted as two conversions explicitly; `B` to `A` and then `A` to `int`. Both could be done by only one user-defined conversion, so it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

[`decltype(auto)`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#decltype-auto)  will get the exact type (including references and pointers) **of the type you're returning**. For `class A` your conversion operator will return an `int`, and for `class B` you will get it to return a `class A`. I think your belief is that `operator decltype(auto) (){/*...*/}` will try to return the class for which the conversion is needed, when in fact you would need a template to do so:

```
class A {
    public:
        int num;
        A ( int param ) : num( param ) {}

        template<class T>
        operator T(){ return static_cast<T>(num); }
};

class B {
    public:
        int num;
        A objA;
        B ( int param ) : num( param ), objA( param ) {}

      template<class T>
      operator T ( ){ return static_cast<T>(objA); }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d345298fa41d68d)

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, its very helpful. However, my main interest is to understand the process of the conversion function, and why it is not working in this case. When the conversion function of `class B` applies and returns a `class A`, do you know why that `class A` cannot be converted to an int? The required conversion sequence is defined (`operator decltype( auto )( ){ return num; }`). Or maybe the conversion function of `class B` did not apply in the first place? Why? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JL It's because user-defined conversions cannot chain. This is what [songyuanyao's answer says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43003042/27678)